# Offline bootstrap like GUI for local Java Application (jar)

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I'm trying to find something that looks or feels like bootstrap but for an application that likely will be run on a computer that cannot connect to the internet. It's a local application so it won't be run in the browser either. I've already got the application running as a .jar file. I just want a way to beautify it as right now it's kind of an ugly piece of work. Are there any useful frameworks for this? I've tried Googling this, but everything I find is for web-apps. I've never had to design for something that wasn't web or mobile so this is new territory for me.

Comment: What do you use Java FX or Swing?

Comment: Swing at the moment. But that's open to change.

Comment: because if you use Java FX, you can rely on css to improve the look and feel of your application, with Swing it is quite limited AFAIK

Comment: I did not know Java FX could work with Css. That's great. I'll look into using that. Thank you.